# Replacing an old dart board ribbon connector - need advice

Tags: cables, repair, ribbon-cable

I hope this makes sense but I have an old dart board that is having some issues I believe is related to the cable in the link below. The cable is a ribbon cable I believe and toward the bottom there is some damage. I tried to tape tightly to create contact but it’s flakey.

I want to cut the ribbon above the injury and then attach the same type of connector, reseat and try to see if that fixes things.

1. Can I do that?
2. Does anyone know what type of connector replacement I would get or where to get it.

I have searched the internet for 19 pin replacement female ribbon connectors and don’t see anything that seems to work where I would insert the freshly cut end of the cable, clamp it down to make contact and then plug it in.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you measure the pitch of the connector? from the pictures it looks like 100 mils (1/10th of an inch). It would greatly help your search.

Comment: take apart some scrap computer keyboards .... they have similar connectors ..... practice connector repair on those

Comment: in the second picture ... the metal traces appear to be corroded

Comment: Don’t have a multimeter. I suppose I should probably just take it to a shop to check that and the possible corrosion mentioned? Do you think a television repair place or computer repair place would work?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply oxidized, use contact cleaner. Whatever you do, don't cut it. Those Flexible Flat Cable or flexible PCB are ONLY intended to be mated at the end where the copper is Tin plated. There should be a way to extract the FFC without cutting it. Those are not soldered they are clipped or pressed in. Also the contact pin is most likely oxidized and could be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have ordered the [cable like that](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4pcs-150mm-0-5mm-1-0mm-Type-A-B-FFC-FPC-Flexible-Flat-Cable-Connector-4P/32863677036.html) just yesterday. Search for "FFC" (flexible flat cable). Or "FFC 1mm" for example, if that is your pitch. There are connectors and [adapters](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5pcs-lot-DIY-Connector-transfer-plate-0-5-to-2-54-FFC-FPC-0-5mm-spacing/32829815114.html) too.

You probably won't find 19 pins though, it's non-standard. But if your connector is OK you should be able to use it with 20 conductors cable.

So, your repair can look like this: Old cable cut above damage > clamped into 20p standard socket > soldered to old 19 pin connector.
Or, if the remaining undamaged part is too short, you can insert a combination of connectors and patch piece of new 20 conductors FFC in between.